# How to iterate through a function each time altering the value of the parameters provided

Tags: swift, function

Hi so I have a class Calculations with a series of functions one of these is keplerianElementsToEcef. In my view controller I hard code the values for the parameters and then call the function. However later on in a seperate class I have a bool isInRange. If my spacecraft is out of cellular range, I return false and a string as well. I also want to then iterate through the keplerianElementsToEcef function, each time increasing the timeOfCalculation parameter by two minutes until at some point in time in the future the satellite is in range.

I've tried to simply call the function but increase the value used initially as the time, current time, by two minutes. The other variables rangeMeanMotion etc, are the same as those hardcoded in the view controller

```
var isInRange: Bool
var rangeString: String
if distance < range {
    isInRange = true
    rangeString = "In Range"
} else {
    isInRange = false
    rangeString = "Not In Range"
    while isInRange == false {

        var dateString = dateFormatter.date(from: calculationTime!)!
        var updatedDate = dateString.addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(5.0 * 60.0))
        var updateDateAsString = dateFormatter.string(from: updatedDate)

        Calculations.shared.keplerianElementsToECEF(meanMotion: rangeMeanMotion, eccentricity: rangeEccentricity, Inclination: rangeInclination, LongitudeAscendingNode: rangeLongitudeAscendingNode, argumentPerigee: rangeArgumentPerigee, M0: rangeM0, epoch: rangeEpoch, date: updateDateAsString) {
      }
   } 
}
```

In the function parameters under date: updateDateAsString I get the following error: Extra argument 'date' in call

Comment: We need to see the declaration of keplerianElementsToECEF

Comment: what will make isInRange true to exit the loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
    var timeOfCalculation : TimeInterval = 0

func doItUntilSpacecraftIsInRange(){
    repeat {
        timeOfCalculation += TimeInterval(2.0 * 60.0)
        Calculations.shared.keplerianElementsToECEF(meanMotion: rangeMeanMotion, eccentricity: rangeEccentricity, Inclination: rangeInclination, LongitudeAscendingNode: rangeLongitudeAscendingNode, argumentPerigee: rangeArgumentPerigee, M0: rangeM0, epoch: rangeEpoch, date: updateDateAsString)

    }  while spacecraft.isInRange == false
}

doItUntilSpacecraftIsInRange()
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. I made the statement iterate during a certain time period (1 day) and my code looks like this:

```
    else {
    isInRange = false
    rangeString = "Not In Range"
    print(calculationTime)

    if let calcTime = calculationTime {
            let parsedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: calcTime) ?? Date()
            for interval in stride(from: 0, to: 1440, by: 2) {
                var updatedDate = parsedDate.addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(interval * 60))
                var updateDateAsString = dateFormatter.string(from: updatedDate)

                Calculations.shared.keplerianElementsToECEF(meanMotion: rangeMeanMotion, eccentricity: rangeEccentricity, Inclination: rangeInclination, LongitudeAscendingNode: rangeLongitudeAscendingNode, argumentPerigee: rangeArgumentPerigee, M0: rangeM0, epoch: rangeEpoch, date: updateDateAsString)

                let xDistance = ecefX - wgs84X
                let yDistance = ecefY - wgs84Y
                let zDistance = ecefZ - wgs84Z

                let iteratedDistance = sqrt(xDistance*xDistance + yDistance*yDistance + zDistance*zDistance)
                if iteratedDistance < 7000 {
                    nextVisible = updateDateAsString
                    break

                }
            }
        }
      }
```